# How to create a menu item with a dynamic dialog message in yii

Tags: yii, popup, cjuidialog

I was looking to put a dynamic popup dialog in a yii menu but am missing a trick to make it dynamic.  (edited: or maybe the question should be 'How can I pass a widget some text through a variable from a menu array) As per the code below:

```
/*Create A Popup Dialog (Gets called from menu)*/
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Menu Alert',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

    echo $dialogText; //Dynamic rather than just static text

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
/* End of Popup Menu*/
//------------------------------------------------
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Help', 'url'=>array('xyz'),'linkOptions' => array('onclick' => '$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;','dialogText'=>'Available Soon')),
);
```

When I use this code, a dialog box appears without the dialog message 'Available Soon'

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` instead of `dialogText` and place it before dialog open

```
 array('label'=>'Help', 'url'=>array('xyz'),'linkOptions' => array('onclick' => '$("#mydialog").text("Available soon"); $("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;')),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is still operating the same as it was before but with your code, it's now just a different style.  Both my original code and your code creates a menu item with the word HELP and when I click on it, it still opens up a dialog box with the title 'Menu Alert' but it's still missing the body of the dialog which I'd like to put some text like 'Available Soon'

Comment: I have tested it is displaying var $dialogText  text in body, Please check whether var contains value or not.

Comment: Hi Hemc, maybe that's my confusion. Can't I embed the value of the variable in the array as shown in the last parameter of the menu item 'dialogText'=>'Available Soon'? That way if I have have multiple menu items which need popups, I can just add that parameter to each item?

Comment: The text 'Available soon' still isn't displaying in the popup body.

Comment: I have edited my answer, now it will output exacttly you want